# How to perform a transform on a matched group in a substitution in python

Tags: python, regex, match

I have an SVG stored in variable and would like to round all path instructions in the data to a certain precision, let’s say 3 digits. I match all floats by matching `\d+.` and the first two digits after the dot `\d{2}` and would then like to round the third digit. I capture all digits after the second to eventually substitute them with a single rounded digit.

The following works, and simply confirms that matching and substituting back the matched groups works:

```
svg = re.sub(r"(\d+\.\d{2})(\d*)", r"\g<1>\g<2>", svg)
```

What I would like to do is sort of like this pseudo code:

```
svg = re.sub(r"(\d+\.\d{2})(\d*)", r"\g<1>" + doSomethingToGroup2(r"\g<2>"), svg)
```

**How can I get access to the second group and manipulate its matched value in this replacement?**

(Presumably what I would like to do to `\g<2>` is something along the lines of `round( int(\g<2>[:1]) / 10 )`, although there might be more elegant ways of doing this — like matching the entire float, multiplying to move the dot position, and rounding and division to move the dot position back.)

---

Edit:
For the curious, this is how I solved it:

```
svg = re.sub(r"(\d+\.\d*)", 
    lambda m: str(round(float(m.group(1)) * 10**precision) / (10**precision)), 
    svg)
```

Comment: Use a callback method or a lambda expression, or combine them, as the second argument to `re.sub`.

Comment: Thanks! Completely missed the example in the docs where the passed in repl can be a callback.